# Regular expression to parse xaml binding-esque syntax

Tags: regex

As usual, regular expressions are causing my head to hurt.

I have the following strings (as examples) which I would like to parse:

```
Client: {Path=ClientName}, Balance: {Path=Balance, StringFormat='{0:0.00}'}
Client: {Path=ClientName}, Balance: {Path=Balance, StringFormat='Your balance is {0:0.00}.'}
```

I am looking for a regular expression (or any other method) which could split the strings as follows and then get the individual key/value values of each. (The idea is to resolve each one of these to a XAML binding)

```
String 1: {Path=ClientName}

    Path = ClientName

String 2: {Path=Balance, StringFormat='{0:0.00}'}

    Path = Balance
    StringFormat = {0:0.00}
```

At the moment I have the following regular expression to split the strings but this gets confused by the value of StringFormat due to the '}' in the value.

```
(?<!'){(.+?)}(?!')
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: As is often true, regex isn't really the best tool for this job. Is there a reason it has to be done with regex?

Comment: To be honest, I just assumed it *could* be done with regex and it was just my ignorance on the topic in the way. I'm really open to any suggestions!

Comment: It *can* be done with a regex, but that's the lazy hack solution. There are better tools for the job, but a regex will probably be "good enough" for most purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets really tiring solving this same problem over and over, but here you go:

Technically, you're doing it wrong, you should use a parser, regular expressions aren't built to deal with nested matching parenthesis, blah blah blah. We can hack this one together, though, so why not?

```
/(?<!'){([^'}]|'[^']+')+}(?!')/
```

The meat of that - `{([^'}]+|'[^']+')}` - looks for two things: a) anything that's not a `}` or a `'` character (`[^'}]`), and b) anything that looks like a string (`'[^']+'`). It assumes a string is a quote, a bunch of non-quote text, and another quote. Given your examples, this should work.

It will, however, fail to match `'This is a string with \'quotes\' in it'`, because it isn't designed for escaped quotation marks. Adding this is simple, and involves applying the principles we just applied, so I'll leave that to you to figure out if you can. You seem to be pretty good with regular expressions, and you at least made a start on this before you asked it, so I think you can figure out how to make it match `\'` in a string.

EDIT: You're using `'`s instead of `"`s. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you read some about the theoretical limitations of regular expressions though. Regexes can match a string with quotes inside (i.e. '\''), but not brackets with brackets inside (i.e. {{}{}}). If the text you want to parse gets much more complicated (especially along the lines of nested parenthesis), you should find another solution. Modern regexes can do it, but it's hacky and unnecessarily difficult to write/read/maintain/upgrade correctly.